# An asynchronous write microphone sound

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Good day.

How to an asynchronous write microphone sound at asp.net mvc?

Needed to record the sound made by the user into a microphone - a voice message.
Can you tell some interesting examples of the sale or, articles on the subject?

Comment: You can't. For recording audio from the user you will need some code to run on the client side. Also...what do you MEAN asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET and MVC are server side and can't access the microphone on the client's computer.

But on the client side you can access the microphone by using:

- [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000298.html)
- ActiveX
- [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Those are my best tips for you.

Regarding **asynchronous** I don't really understand what you want.